# entity framework output parameter from store procedure.it adds the record fine but i need id of newly inserted record back

Tags: entity-framework

here is my code
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter output = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("userID", typeof(int));
db.Proc_UserAccounts_AddNew(output, obj.Name, obj.Password, obj.SignUpDate, obj.Inactive, obj.Address, obj.Phone,
obj.Email, obj.VerificationCode, obj.Cell, obj.Fax, countryid, null, 10, obj.ServiceDescription, "", "", "", "", "", "1", null,
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: var userid = output.Value;

Comment: just evalute to nul,